Trouble bridging edges between circles without creating unwanted patterns
I'm new to Blender and struggling with bridging two circles. Despite trying various walkthroughs and researching technical terms, I can't seem to bridge the edges between the circles without creating a scallop pattern on the inner circle. I'm trying to create a precision piece, and adjusting a cylinder has proven to be difficult. I've included some screenshots in case someone can pinpoint where my understanding is lacking.



Could you describe the steps you used to make your object? Or upload the blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

It looks to me like you may be trying to bridge two halves or sides of the same edge loop- rather than two 'closed loops'.

The only way so far I've been able to reproduce something like this (though not exactly the same),  is to attempt to bridge loops on faces in opposite orientations: https://imgur.com/a/1UHR5iH . Is that it? If so, Alt-N > Flip the inner face.

In the edge example at least, you've got all the interior edges selected, that's not going to work

Bridge Edge Loops is a very predictable and dependable tool- a workhorse.
It looks like you selected a parts of two loops on the same mesh with an uneven number of points on either side.  Here, I am trying to reproduce your problem:


Bridge edge loops works well with closed loops with identical points.
For example, If I duplicate and resized the loop at the top of a cylinder which has no top face, and then used bridge edge loop, it would result in an even 'bridge' between the two loops.


The default cylinder in blender is not good for every use case.
If you wanted to model a bolt, or a coke can for example, you might want a different topology on the top.
I have found grid fill rather than bridge edge loops can work very well.



Hehe.. that didn't occur to me.
